# C# WPF UserControls are not in the windows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

the MainWindow Code is like this:

```
<Window x:Class="UserGUI.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserGUI"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="657.278" Width="952.33" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
<Canvas>
    <ContentControl Name="mainContentControl" Grid.Column="0" Height="585" Width="934" Canvas.Top="31"/>
    <ContentControl Name="upperMenu" Grid.Column="1" Height="31" Width="944"/>
</Canvas>
```

and the xaml is:

```
        public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mainContentControl.Content = new AdminMenu();
        upperMenu.Content = new LoginScreen();
    }
```

But I do not see the user controls in my mainwindow...
It seems they are not aligned at all

What am i doing wrong?
The LoginScreen Canvas is:

```
   <Canvas x:Name="loginCanvas" Background="BlanchedAlmond" Height="620" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="934">
```

and the window of the userControl window itself is:

```
Height="630" Width="944">
```

Hope i'm clear enough

Comment: No, you are not clear enough. What is AdminMenu and LoginScreen. Where are they located. Show all code

Answer (score 0):

There are some strange things in your XAML. There is no Grid and no columns, but you have some positioning based on it. Try this:

```
<Window x:Class="UserGUI.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserGUI"
Title="MainWindow" Height="657.278" Width="952.33" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
<Canvas>
<ContentControl Name="mainContentControl" Height="585" Width="934" Canvas.Top="31" Canvas.Left="0"/>
<ContentControl Name="upperMenu" Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0" Height="31" Width="944"/>
</Canvas>
```